# Sharepoint Migration from 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How to migrate webparts from 2010 to sharepoint 2013

I have mouted datbase with my new site on sharepoint 2013 but when i open it it say something went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Without further details I would say to check the logs with the correlation ID. It should be on the logs folder under the 15 hive.

For migration I would recommend this 3 articles:

[Migrating the Database and Site Collection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Don't forget to check if the database was sucessfully updated in the central administration -> Upgrade and Migration -> Review database status.

Also if you have custom solutions check this before upgrading the database:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn673579%28v=office.15%29.aspx

And don't forget that sharepoint 2013 has a 2010 mode so they should be deployed to the 14 hive also (check the first image on the link above for a good overview)

Finally, also because sharepoint 2013 has 2010 mode you have to take notice to point your control templates to the correct hive:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn296464%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: You need to create a 2013 master page with the placeholders that your page layout is looking for.
There many approaches to this. I usually work with Visual studio and package master pages. I begin with the minimumV15.master and edit it with my custom stuff (the previous master page can help a lot), than deploy it. If don't want to use visual studio you have two more options. Sharepoint Design Manager and SharePoint Designer 2013. Just search and there are a lot of articles about each, specially Sharepoint Designer (Sharepoint Design Manager is new so fewer articles).

Comment: Can't i use the exiting master page of 2013 , and how can I migrate css, javascript and images.

Comment: You can if you create a page based on a different page layout, but you should be using custom page layouts that are expecting some placeholders that are not found on that master page.
This should mean that most personalization you had is gone if you change the page layout.
Has for JS and CSS It depends on how you were maintaining those files, but for now, at least, your problem is between the master page and the page layout not CSS and JS.
Before making a migration, you should know how Sharepoint works, which does not seem to be the case...

Comment: yes this is my first task in sharepoint , can u give me any link which can help me to understand how to deal with master pages , control templates etc

Comment: How Can I update path of usercontols that are used in pages ?